# Android apk sign information

Tags: android, apk, sign

Where in the apk stored sign information?
apk file is zip archive with .apk extension. Can I change some recourses or it will affect the signature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this method below you can edit resourses, but you have to resign the apk but that is shown below as well. This example edits an image resource but this can be used with any resource

First use the tool “aapt” from the android SDK to list the resources:

```
$ANDROID/tools/aapt list file.apk
```

Once we locate the resources that we need to change, we use “remove” and “add” to replace them:

```
$ANDROID/tools/aapt remove file.apk res/drawable/file.png
$ANDROID/tools/aapt add file.apk res/drawable/file.png
```

Then we have to remove the old APK signature and replace it with a new one.
We will generate a fake self signed key to sign the APK:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out key.pem 1024
$ openssl req -new -key key.pem -out request.pem
$ openssl x509 -req -days 9999 -in request.pem -signkey key.pem -out certificate.pem
$ openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -outform DER -in key.pem -inform PEM -out key.pk8 -nocrypt
```

Remove the old signature from the APK:

```
for f in `$ANDROID/tools/aapt list file.apk |grep "META-INF"` ; do
$ANDROID/tools/aapt remove file.apk $f
done
```

And now we sign the APK, I use signapk.jar to do this:

```
$ java -jar signapk.jar certificate.pem key.pk8 file.apk file-signed.apk
```

Comment: It is clear, thank you. But I still do not understand where the is physically signature information stored.

Comment: If you look inside the apk, you'll find a META-INF/CERT.SF file that list all files in your apk and their hash value. this file is signed, and the signature is in the META-INF/CERT.RSA file.